# Bootstrap: Class reference

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This may seem like a dumb question, but is there an official bootstrap class reference? I looked on the website and was unable to find one.

I'm looking though some of the examples and I'll see stuff like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

How am I supposed to figure out what all the `contain-fluid` tag does? Am I expected to dig through the css for every class to look at the rules and then divine how it will affect my page? That seems like a quick way to make assumptions and run into problems later.

Is there an official reference somewhere that I'm missing? I've seen some class lists compiled by third parties, but it seems like those are always going to lag behind new changes and may contain assumptions of intensions.

Comment: not entirely sure what your asking but if your looking for an explanation as to what different parts of the bootstrap styling do check out the examples on their site here.
http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: adding fluid to a container will make that section split into 12 pieces no matter how big it is. so if you have a standard container with a span 6 section in it and then within that a fluid container, it should make the 6 sections into 12.
handy way of keeping the grid format and increasing accuracy.

Comment: About the fluid : RTFM http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem for BT2 Or http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for BT3

Comment: @TheLittlePig: That manual is what I was asking for in my original post. I couldn't FR it if I couldn't F-ing find it. When I look at the main bootstrap website, the only link I see for the documentation is at the very bottom of an incredibly long web page. RTFM is a terrible way to answer a question because it assumes that the person has not already tried. arg0, Thanks for the explanation and the point to the site. I don't think the main bootstrap site's examples are as clear, but the 2.3.2 section of the site is a bit more clear.

Comment: @TheLittlePig, you pointed me to an outdated version. It's frustrating. You go to any other framework and you get a list of commands, components, classes, etc with an explanation of each does. This is what I'm looking for with bootstrap. For example, I'm looking at the navbar example on the bootstrap page and I see the class "navbar-toggle". There is literally nothing on the page that explains what that class does. I can infer what it does from it's name and by looking at the example, but there is not a reference that says what it's meant to do, or why the data attribute is needed, etc.

Comment: The point isn't that it can't be figured out, it's just frustrating that you have to infer rather than, say, wanting to know what the jquery `blur` method does and being able to look at the page http://api.jquery.com/blur/ which explains exactly what it does. As far as I've seen so far that doesn't exist for bootstrap.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz Yes it's very frustrating. I gave you a link for the old and new version, and you choose the wrong, well.... When I click on getbootstrap.com/css/#grid the first thing I see in red is 'container-fluid'... Maybe there is no list as you would like, but a lot of developpers have learn just with this doc, and there was no problem for us...

Comment: @thelittlepig yeah, I had already read the section on the grid from the main docs. My hope was that I somehow got the version numbers mixed up and you passing me the right versions docs. I'm sure the docs current docs work for a lot of people. I was just hoping for a more standard reference and one that actually explains all of the tools rather than just most of them.

Comment: http://blog.seosemanticxhtml.com/a-complete-reference-library-of-bootstrap-classes/

Comment: Holy cow, thank you very much! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. The fact that it has an explanation of the class AND a link back to the relevant section of the original docs makes it perfect. Thank you! Also, sorry for my general anger in replies. The styling portion of the project is frustrating (while I know how to style, I don't actually enjoy it) and I personally get really offended at RTFM comments because of the assumptions they make so I flew off the handle. Thank you for the help.

Comment: http://blog.seosemanticxhtml.com/a-complete-reference-library-of-bootstrap-classes/ seems to refer to Bootstrap 2.3.2, not Bootstrap 3.  And the lack of obvious organization (headings between sections of related classes would be nice) makes it a really tough read.  So I assume that the answer is "no, the only way to figure it out is to dig through examples and try to figure out the what, why, and wherefore of the various classes sprinkled therein...

Comment: Yeah, while I don't think it's the best solution possible, it was at least enough to make me feel a bit more comfortable as I was learning it. It's just frustrating building with assumption rather than certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_quick_guide.htm contains a very good reference for many of the bootstrap layout and css components.

Comment: Nice, thank you! This has a lot of the explanations I was looking for. I appreciate the link.

Answer (score 3):

Not official but current as of 2/2016 https://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-3-css-classes-index/

Printable pdf and a sortable table with descriptions to help sort through the list of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 moved to a "mobile first" approach. .container is really only there in instances where you need/want a boxy layout. but, if you exempt the div.container-fluid entirely, you're left with a fluid layout by default.

for example, to have a two-column fluid layout, simply use:

```
<body>
<header>...</header>
<div style="padding:0 15px;"><!-- offset row negative padding -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">50%</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">50%</div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

The 2.x .container-fluid was replaced by .container in Bootstrap 3.x (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration), so the .container is fluid, but it's not full width.

You can use the row as a fluid container, but you must tweak it a little to avoid a horizontal scroll bar. Excerpt from the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)..

"Folks looking to create fully fluid layouts (meaning your site stretches the entire width of the viewport) must wrap their grid content in a containing element with padding: 0 15px; to offset the margin: 0 -15px; used on .rows."

More on changes in 3.x: http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Demo: http://bootply.com/91948

UPDATE for Bootstrap 3.1

container-fluid has returned again in Bootstrap 3.1. Now container-fluid can be used to create a full width layout: http://www.bootply.com/116382